# How to run a function for certain period of time in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I made a counter component using touchableopacity,
What I want to do is keep adding 1 until user holds the button and stop when they leave it,
I also want to just add 1 when user taps the add button.

What I have tried is I started a loop on pressIn with a time interval so the whole process looks good but I couldn't stop the loop on pressout

Comment: can you please share the logic you have tried in the code so that we could guide you through it! seemingly you are half closer to the solution though :-)

Comment: @Rizwan atta, Thank you for your response I resolved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved,
What I did is onPressIn called my add function inside an interval of 500 and onpressout cleared that interval

**Here is the code snippet for better understanding**

```
add = () => {
    this.setState(p=>{
        return{
            ...p,
            number:p.number + 1
        }
    })
} 
addLoop = () => {
    this.addInterval = setInterval(this.add,500)
}
stopAdding = () => {
    clearInterval(this.addInterval)
}
```

**and in my touchableOpacity called it like this**

```
onPressOut={this.stopAdding} onPressIn={this.addLoop} onPress={this.add}
```